# Making Ubuntu Server an every day desktop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, window-manager

I am using Ubuntu Desktop as my operating system in the last months and now I want to install Ubuntu Server and configure it as my desktop. I want to learn more about Linux and what programs are needed during every day operations. While I was using Ubuntu Desktop all basic utilities were there and never found out what is really going on. My plan is to install a window manager, login manager and whatever else will be needed. Any tips for starting out (basic programs, wm recommendations etc.)?

Comment: If you want to understand linux to an extremely low level, I suggest looking at Linux from scratch. Making a working system from just a kernel and a handful of files is totally doable in a short time if you have the knowledge. https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/

Comment: Welcome to the community. I'd suggest checking out the help section, (https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) on how to ask questions. Firstly, as you're asking an Ubuntu-specific question you're on the wrong community. Secondly, in general StackExchange is a place for help in resolving specific issues; you're asking for tips and recommendations. As the possible answers are necessarily subjective, (compare Hack Saw's comment to mzamorar's answer) those are off-topic in StackExchange sites. I'd recommend deleting the question and going to Ubuntu's own forums for this kind of help.

Comment: @Peregrino69 Ubuntu is a Linux and, as such, is 100% on topic here. You are right that this question is too broad and opinion based and so is off topic here, but the fact that it is about Ubuntu is not relevant at all.

Comment: Jimmy, if you want a Desktop system then just use Ubuntu. What you are describing, converting Ubuntu Server to work as a Desktop system is exactly what you get when you install a regular Ubuntu. There is no point in installing Server and then trying to make it into Desktop. If you want to learn more about Linux, just use a different distribution like Arch.

Comment: @terdon Ubuntu being on-topic is maybe a bit of a grey area in this case. The Help / What topics section says "Note that Ubuntu posts are a special case" referring to Ask Ubuntu, and the OP seems to make very clear he's interested in Ubuntu only, not Linux in general - so in my eyes this'd be more appropriate to Ask Ubuntu (and maybe Software Recommendations) :-) Actually Ubuntu's own community would be my resource of choice for this question presented as is.

Comment: @Peregrino69 Yeah, that help article isn't very well written, I can see why it would be confusing. The point is that Ubuntu-specific stuff are likely to get better answers on AU but Ubuntu has always been 100% on topic here too. I have now updated the page to make that clearer.

Comment: @terdon Seems clearer now indeed :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using Ubuntu Server Minimal install does help understanding how servers work since only a set of services and applications are running on the system. I would not start with Linux linuxfromscratch.org unless you are an enthusiast since it could be overwhelming due to the low level explanations.

If you want to learn more about Linux, I recommend The Linux Command Line Book (on Amazon) or EBook https://linuxcommand.org/tlcl.php , the book explains services, applications, and most things to an associate level.

Do not complicate your learning by installing Arch, Gentoo, etc. Start with a good dose of everything in general and then pursue something specifically.